# Moving iPhone backup to new Itunes installation

Tags: iphone, backup, itunes

I'm going to format my computer soon and plugging the iphone in the fresh itunes installation will erase all data/settings from it, correct?

Is there a way to move the iphone backup data from the old itunes to the new itunes? things like calendar items, mail accounts, settings, etc.

Comment: Are you using a Mac or PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the data and settings will not be erased. You can set it so that the new computer can copy the data off the iPhone and re-use it when you plug it in.

That said, there's no need to move the iphone backup data over to the new itunes. Just format, reconnect, choose the options necessary to copy the data back from the iphone to the reformatted com, and voila! You are ready to go.

One thing : Music must be copied over from the old iTunes to the new iTunes. The rest is not necessary.

Comment: If you really want to have a backup just to be safe, refer to this thread. http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/1245100.html

Comment: -1: According to the [knowledge base](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1329), you can only copy songs from the iTunes, not from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  iTunes saves the backup files in this folder /Users/username/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup

They should be there. Back those files and restore them to that folder when you are done formatting.